# Why Ramanuja did not see the injury mark on Lord Venkateshwara's head?

Tags: gods, venkateshwara

The story of milkman hitting Lord Venkateshwara happened long before Ramanujacharya, but why he did not see the injury mark on Lord Venkateshwara's face?

That mark is enough to prove that the idol is of Lord Venkateshwara Swami's right? then how come he missed to mention about it while proving the idol?

I also heard about a story mentioning the reason for donating the hair is that Swami lost his hair because of this injury only on his head, then why it is not considered while proving?

Is it really the Lord Venkateshwara's idol only?

Lord Venkatesheara Swami idol is somewhere else which is yet to be revealed?